# trying to use usedispatch hook with userefs but it does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-state-management

I have been experimenting with the Redux useDispatch hook. I made this super simple app of writing down notes as a todo list. Until now useDispatch does not seem to work for me and I get the following error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Louaye Mandari\Desktop\redux-todo-list\redux-todo-list\src\App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (17:26)

  15 |   const handleClicked = (e) =>{
  16 |     e.preventDefault();
> 17 |     dispatch(addTask({text.current.value}))
     |                           ^
  18 |   }
  19 |   return (
  20 |     <div className="App">
```

**App.js**

```
import { useSelector,useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import taskSlice from './redux/taskSlice';
import './App.css';
import { useState,useRef } from 'react';
import { addTask } from './redux/taskSlice';

function App() {
  const data = useSelector(state=>state.tasks)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const text = useRef()
  const handleClicked = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(addTask({text.current.value}))
  }
  return (
    <div className="App"> 
      <button onClick={handleClicked}>
        Enter the new task 
      </button>
      <input type='text' ref = {text} placeholder='write the task here' />  
      <label>{data.task[data.task.length - 1]} </label>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

**taskSlice.js:**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const taskSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'tasks',
  initialState: {
    task: ['hi'],
  },
  reducers: {
    addTask: (state, action) => {
      state.tasks.push(action.payload);
    },
  },
});

export const { addTask } = taskSlice.actions;
export default taskSlice.reducer;
```

**store.js**:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import taskReducer from "./taskSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    tasks: taskReducer,
  },
});
```

I am trying to access `addtask` in reducers in taskslice.js. The addtask should turn the new state and add a new element to the initial state of task array.

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple issues, but the first comes from this line

```
dispatch(addTask({text.current.value}))
```

The `{text.current.value}` is incorrect. It looks like you are trying to do [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Think about what should the `addTask` take in as an input: a string? An object? What kind of object?

---

To focus on the destructuring error, what you are trying to do is kind of like this:

```js
const animal = { name: { first: "Rauli", last: "Cat" }, age: 7 }
console.log({animal.name.first})
```

This gives you the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`. In my example assuming I want to just log the name, I probably want to do something like this instead:

```js
const animal = { name: { first: "Rauli", last: "Cat" }, age: 7 }
console.log(animal.name.first)
```